# why does line() not always return a line-object? why does it sometimes seem to return a double?

Tags: matlab, line, return-value

I know the line(X,Y) command returns a line object.
Thats why I dont understand the following code:

```
myline=line([1 2],[1 1]);
x=[];
x(2,2)=myline
```

This returns 
x = [0 0; 0 7.0001]
Why?  Why the 7.0001? why is x(2,2) not a line object?

```
isfloat(x(2,2))  %this returns true
isgraphics(x(2,2),'line')  %this also  returns true!
set(x(2,2),'LineStyle','--')  %this works fine
x(2,2)+1    %this also works fine!
```

How can x(2,2) be a float and a line object at the same time?? And why is it a float at the beginning?

If the answer to this question is long and complicated, I am also happy with just a link to somewhere, where this behaviour is explained.
(I know these are technically more than one question. But it seems to me they all belong together and have the same answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a combination of MATLAB's assignment rules together with the compatibility layer between the old and new handle graphics systems.

Firstly, when you make a assignment into an array (including when you assign "off the end" of the array), the type of that array never changes - instead, the type of the right-hand-side is converted (if possible) to match the array you're assigning into. In your case, by executing `x = []`, you're making `x` be a `0x0` array of type `double`. When you assign to the `(2,2)` element, the `line` object is converted to `double`.

The fact that you can convert a `line` object to a `double` value is for compatibility with MATLAB's old implementation of handle graphics. The original handle graphics system was developed before MATLAB had a fully-featured object-oriented programming system, and so instead of things like `line` objects, all graphics objects were represented by unique double-precision numbers. In the new system, to maintain backwards compatibility with old code, it's still possible to treat `line` objects etc. as double-precision numbers.

You can see this behaviour explicitly by calling

```
double(myline)
```

You can use [`gobjects`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gobjects.html) to assign an empty array of graphics placeholder elements instead if you wish:

```
myline = line([1 2],[1 1])
x = gobjects(0);
x(2,2) = myline;
class(x(2,2)) % gets 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
```